# .NET core minmal APIs not connecting with react native app (Expo CLI)

Tags: .net, react-native, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, react-native-navigation

I am trying to connect my .Net core minmal apis backend with react native but it keeps giving me network error, I dont know what I am doing wrong. I have double checked the url the ip address too many times but still could not make it to work. Please , I would appreciate your help.

I have tried the same application with a node backend it worked fine for node, may be because node was using http while .net backend is using https but I still do not understand if there is any thing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to post the code and error messages as text in your question. [Screenshots are not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).,

Comment: Please share  more details about the ERR_NETWORK.

Comment: You also could try to use ngrok to expose the react app with https, check re-check it. And check the CORS settings both front-end and backend project.